# cassandra error "Batch too large" using python

Tags: python, json, cassandra, cqlsh

i'm trying to insert json file into a cassandra table by retrieving columns from the json using json module then inserting it into cassandra using prepared statement.The file is 2778ko precisely.I can't figure out how to insert it.Please help !!!

```
query = """
        INSERT INTO profile9 (id,profilelegacy,profilealternative,aboutlegacy,skills,recommendations,accomplishments,peoplealsoviewed,volunteerExperience,profile)
          VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);

          """

        insert_user = session.prepare(query)
        batch = BatchStatement(consistency_level=ConsistencyLevel.ONE)
        batch.add(insert_user, (idd, profileLegacy, profilealternative, aboutlegacy, skills,
                                recommendations, accomplishments, peopleAlsoviewed, volunteerExperience, profile,))
        log = logging.getLogger()
        log.info('Batch Insert Completed')
        session.execute(batch)
```

I get this error

```
line 64, in parsing
    session.execute(batch)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\cassandra\cluster.py", line 2240, in execute
    timeout, execution_profile, paging_state, host).result()
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\cassandra\cluster.py", line 4198, in result
    raise self._final_exception
cassandra.InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Batch too large"
```

Answer (score 2):

Theres no reason to use a batch here, it will only make things slower and impose the size limitation. Just change it to:

```
# only prepare this once
prepared = session.prepare(query)
...
session.execute(prepared.bind((idd, profileLegacy, profilealternative, aboutlegacy, skills,
                        recommendations, accomplishments, peopleAlsoviewed, volunteerExperience, profile,)))
```